# Import all files from a folder in VSCode Studio Code Webview API

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am importing json files as following:

```
import input1 = require("../test/test1.json");
import input2 = require("../test/test2.json");
import input3 = require("../test/test3.json");
import input4 = require("../test/test4.json");
import input5 = require("../test/test5.json");
```

My tsconfig settings is:

```
"module": "commonjs",
"target": "es6",
```

But I need to import the whole "test" folder with a lot of json files. How can I import all the files and assign each file to a "input" variable?

**Update:**

I have tried the following code that was suggested by @Michael. But is gives following error.

```
const fs = require('fs');

let testDataPath = "../test"
let filenames = fs.readdirSync(testDataPath)

filenames = filenames.filter(it => it.endsWith(".json"))
let runvalue = [];
for(let filename of filenames) {
   let file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(testDataPath + "/" + filename, "utf-8"))
   let json = Object.values(file["covered-points"]);
    runvalue = [...runvalue, new Set(json)]
}
```

But its giving error: `"Uncaught TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function"`

I can't figure out whats wrong with "fs" in visual studio code. Someone please help me. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are in NodeJS rather than in a web browser, the best way would be to use the `fs` core module to read the directory contents, and then the file contents. Eg:

```
let testDataPath = "./test"
let filenames = fs.readdirSync(testDataPath)
filenames = filenames.filter(it => it.endsWith(".json"))

for(let filename of filenames) {
   let json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(testDataPath + "/" + filename, "utf-8"))
   //do something with the json
}
```

Note:

- In general you should use the asynchronous versions of these functions, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you to do
- The path given needs to be relative to the current working directory of the program, rather than the file the function is called in

ref: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: I am working with Typescript in Visual studio code webview api.  I have tried
import * as fs from 'fs';

let testDataPath = "../test"
let filenames = fs.readdirSync(testDataPath)
filenames = filenames.filter(it => it.endsWith(".json"))
let runvalue = [];
for(let filename of filenames) {
   let file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(testDataPath + "/" + filename, "utf-8"))
   let json = Object.values(file["all-points"]);
    runvalue = [...runvalue, new Set(json)]
}
But its giving error: "Uncaught TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function"

Comment: How are you running the code? If this is being run in NodeJS then it should work fine

Comment: Its Visual studio code webview api. The typescript converts to javascript and runs as a web extension. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with writing vscode extensions - you should edit your question to include this detail as it's important